# TDD testing in C. Pass Swap and Sort Tests?

Tags: c, sorting, testing, swap

I'm coding in C. I wrote the code for a Swap method and a Bubble Sort method but I have no idea how to run TDD tests for them. Could you show me how to create TDD tests to verify that each of these methods properly works? Here's the code for each of my methods:

```
/**
* swaps the values referenced by p and q
*/
void swap (int *p, int *q)
{
   int tmp; 

   tmp = *p; 
   *p = *q; 
   *q = tmp; 
}

/**
* an implementation of bubble sort
* n is the size of array a
*/
void bubble (int a[], int n)
{
   int i, j; 

   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
     for (j = n-1; i < j; j--)
      {
       if (a[j-1] > a[j])
      {
         swap (&a[j-1], &a[j]); 
      }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the question a joke? How can you do test driven development if the implementation is done before the tests are written?

Comment: I didn't think it was possible either but my professor persisted to make me write the code first and then write the tests to verify that the code work. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I think your professor is actually asking for a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea around a unit test. You test a small part of your code in isolation. If this test is passing but the sort isn't working, you'll know that the error is in the sort implementation and not the swap.

```
void testSwap() {
  int a = 0;
  int b = 1;

  swap(&a, &b);
  if (a == 1)
    printf("ok");
  if (b == 0)
    printf("ok");
}
```

You would be doing TDD if you write the testSwap() function before you implement the swap() function.